# Introducir fichero txt en un datagridview

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Hola tengo una duda de como mandar mis registros de un fichero con extension **txt** a un **DataGridView** trabajo con **C++** en Visual Studio 2012

Les adjunto un ejemplo de como tengo el fichero txt

> Codigo, Nombre, Telefono, Correo, Direccion
>   01, Samuel, 222244444, sam@gmail.com, ciudad

Y todos estos campos los guardo al fichero.txt con textbox y los va guardando linea por linea con

> WriteLine(Aqui mis textbox con sus respectivas variables y delimitador **,**);
>   Ejemplo: WriteLine(codigo->ToString()+",") y asi sucesivamente con los demas.

Lo unico que no encuentro es mandar toda mi infomacion del fichero al datagridView con esos datos guardados anteriormente.
Y lo otro tambien a la vez, ¿como agregar los encabezados respectivos de cada columnna es decir, **Codigo, Nombre, Telefono, Correo, Direccion ***

De ante mano muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu **fichero.txt**, agrégale un caracter al inicio de tu encabezado, yo usaré `;`:

> ;Codigo,Nombre,Telefono,Correo,Direccion

Luego, lees todas las líneas de tu fichero utilizando *StreamReader*:

```
StreamReader^ sr = gcnew StreamReader( "fichero.txt" );
try
{
    String^ linea;

    //Creamos un array que almacenará nuestras lineas tratadas
    array<String^>^ lineaArray;

    //Empieza a leer lineas
    while ( linea = sr->ReadLine() )
    {
        //Comprueba que la linea que contiene (;) es de los encabezados.
        if( linea->Contains( ";" )) 
        {
            //Reemplazamos (;) y nos quedaría una cadena (Codigo,Nombre,Telefono,Correo,Direccion)
            String^ encabezados = linea->Replace( ";" , "" );                   

            //con "Split(',')" extraemos cada palabra separada por (,)
            //devolviendo un array: {"Codigo", "Nombre", "Telefono", "Correo", "Direccion"}
            lineaArray = encabezados->Split( ',' )

            //Luego le cambiamos el nombre a las cabeceras de nuestro DataGridView
            //usando "lineaArray"
            columna1->HeaderText = lineaArray[0];
            columna2->HeaderText = lineaArray[1];
            columna3->HeaderText = lineaArray[2];
            columna4->HeaderText = lineaArray[3];
            columna5->HeaderText = lineaArray[4];

            //Continuamos leyendo la siguiente linea
            continue;
        }               

        lineaArray = linea->Split( ',' );
        dataGridView1->Rows->Add( lineaArray );

    }
}
finally
{
    if ( sr )
        delete (IDisposable^)sr;
}
```

Recomiendo no usar espacios después de cada `,`. De lo contrario, al hacer `Split()`, devuelve un espacio antes de cada palabra.

Comment: Hola! Pues si funciona de esa misma manera, solo que al final yo use un ciclo for que va recorriendo toda las columnas y añade lo que tengo en mi fichero.txt
Igual **muchas gracias** tambien es util hacerlo asi como exlicas